# Can't install anything with pip2 on Windows 7 due to UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: windows, python-2.7, windows-7, pip

I'm trying to install Django (with another package the error is the same) for Python 2.7.10/Windows 7 with pip, and getting this strange error

Command is

> pip install django

Sorry, but I can't write an entire log because of dumb Windows console. Here is the second part of log.

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\resp
onse.py", line 307, in stream
data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\resp
onse.py", line 243, in read
data = self._fp.read(amt)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py",
line 54, in read
self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\controller.py", l
ine 244, in cache_response
self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 276, in set
return super(SafeFileCache, self).set(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\caches\file_cache
.py", line 99, in set
with self.lock_class(name) as lock:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\lockfile\mkdirlockfile.py", li
ne 18, in __init__
LockBase.__init__(self, path, threaded, timeout)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\lockfile\__init__.py", line 18
9, in __init__
hash(self.path)))
File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 85, in join
result_path = result_path + p_path
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

May be it's because of cyrillic username that runs the system. Is there a way to fix it without creating a new user?

Or maybe there is some bad thing that I missed?

Comment: The code in `ntpath` has problems with mixing byte strings and unicode strings in Python 2. As you see it use the default ASCII encoding instead of MBCS/ANSI. I've seen related problems multiple times on CPython's bug tracker and several related questions on Stack Overflow. However, I don't think it will ever be fixed unless someone steps up to write a patch with tests. The core devs have almost zero interest in updating the 2.7 branch. So just use an ASCII profile directory (not necessarily username), or prepare to be burned by this again later.

Comment: It's possible to change your profile directory by editing the registry, but messy and easy to mess up. It's simpler to create a new user with an ASCII name and then change the username to whatever you want.